# How to use curl -w switch with multiple data token as format parameter?

Tags: bash, curl

I want to get two things from curl: `http_code` and `time_total` from a single `curl` request. How should I formulate the `-w %{insert_formatting_here}` ?

These works:

```
result = $(curl -s -w %{http_code} -o temp.txt) "http://127.0.0.1" 
echo "$result"
result = $(curl -s -w %{time_total} -o temp.txt) "http://127.0.0.1" 
echo "$result"
```

Result:

```
200
0.004
```

But this didn't work as I expected:

```
result = $(curl -s -w %{http_code time_total} -o temp.txt) "http://127.0.0.1" 
echo "$result"
```

Result:

```
<p>where "$CATALINA_HOME" is the root of the Tomcat installation directory. If you're seeing this page, and you don't think you should be, then you're either a user who has arrived at new installation of Tomcat, or you're an administrator who hasn't got his/her setup quite right. Providing the latter is the case, please refer to the <a href="/docs">Tomcat Documentation</a> for more detailed setup and administration in %{http_codeReserved99-2014 Apache Software Foundation<br/>ht="80" alt="Powered by Tomcat"/><br/>s working on Tomcat</li>configuring and using Tomcat</li> developing web applications.</p>
```

I cannot find any tutorial that helps me to put multiple token on the format parameter. They only list the format token, but there's no example or anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each placeholder needs to be in brackets, i.e.:

```
curl -s -w "%{http_code}:%{time_total}" http://127.0.0.1
```